# I compared the value of two columns for equality and I want to see in the output only different values from two compaired columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, exploratory-data-analysis

So I have a dataframe of 168 rows and 121 columns. There are some columns that I want to compare and display the different values.

The code is:

```
comparison_column = np.where((df_full["Name"] == df_full["Displ_name"]), True, False)
print(comparison_column)
```

output is a list with True and False.

I used apply method with lambda, but it shows not only rows with different values but also all columns from the dataframe. Is there a method which can display rows with different value but only from compared columns?

```
df_full[df_full.apply(lambda x: x["Name"] != x["Displ_name"], axis=1)]
```

Comment: Use `df1 = df[(df_full["Name"] != df_full["Displ_name"]]`

Comment: Nope, still the same quantity of columns, I just need the different values to be shown from compared columns